# External monitor speakers not working via usb-c

Tags: sound, kubuntu, external-monitor

I have a Dell monitor 38" ultrawide but the speakers are not working over USB-c nor are they detected in sound settings. Thoughts?

Comment: May be speakers available with hdmi connection only

Comment: Have you tested the monitor with the same connection in a different OS?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 18.04 and that monitor. No sound from the monitor when connecting with a USB C or HDMI cable. Worked fine with Windows. Running `aplay -l` didn't even show anything other than the laptop speakers.

But after rebooting both the laptop and the monitor, `aplay -l` started showing more:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC257 Analog [ALC257 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Then I ran `pavucontrol` and went in the Configuration tab and picked the profile for "Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)" output and analog input. That did the trick. A whole bunch of other profiles were listed , but none of them seemed to do any good.

Comment: pavucontrol worked for me on PopOS 19.10  - selecting "Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output" worked for my USB-C connected monitor.